# Determinant of a sub-matrix of the classical adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, determinants, exterior-algebra

Let $A$ be a  square matrix of order $n$, say with complex coefficients, and let $M$ be the plain matrix of minors  of $A$ of order $n-1$ (no transpose, no sing changes). Let $I$ and $J$ be $r$-subsets of the index set $[n]$. Then, apparently
$$\det M_{I\times J}=\det A_{([n]\setminus I)\times ([n]\setminus J)}\det(A)^{r-1}.$$
(One can also write the identity for the classical adjoint of $A$ instead of $M$, or also assume $A$ invertible, and express the identity in terms of $A^{-1}$).

So for $r=1$ this is just the definition of $M_{ij}$. For small values of $n$, it is possible to check the identity, keeping track of the terms of the expansion of the determinant.  But is there a more synthetic proof, and an interpretation of it?

Comment: The case when M is the classical cofactor matrix was discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87877/jacobis-equality-between-complementary-minors-of-inverse-matrices).

Comment: "Plain matrix of minors" = plain matrix of $\left(n-1\right)\times\left(n-1\right)$-minors?

Comment: @darij grinberg: Yep. Btw, I like very much your exterior algebra duality interpretation, which is what I wished!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me, a standard book to look for such things is Prasolov's linear algebra. This is Theorem 1.2.6.1. [Here](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?bu=uniq1513695095152581690&from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=1640.ah88ixYOrS1RaE-8FQAFl2dCq8EWwxpqqPiGeK_YJ0K1Ebi3-a2TB5wpPqw82NkR42UkdRXxHsAPf4fCsmuWHw.799bfc877d6aa36ba4d848d8b38f55a03911e7fd&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9T6U0-imFY5IshtIYWJN7W-V64A9Yd8Kv-PJgis4UdqY898U4_M9m97MEdQj08ewT2T1q7xm1hB0YfP0njom1fg,&&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5fN_r-AEszk96e2nDyuYBNtTIvrmHQK3-sNGTm3-JC5dMymoknB9ozxA7v5zbX_SbUbZwslPfPKs69VUf13BldESxC36iniIvz8oifrIfsc_xq3s_-eNwgRBIK-_z-eS0V5VHsqzRPgnPJXVi94Sn48Lsn1pNCxrRX8vFv5_vxa1JikjABz5iH8zuSyzndk0zZeWS5XyF5uAuCFjGCkDaaJXT0Tll-14r-O-dqqZCzKIg3cDPiFrQcWwKTUHld6cS0kGrYtztH2_8pdCnqqzWfnt3T1NiGAUh3T8PlzbbJjVaeBalUhcb0hRtad6QcOIGycfT195C_ieOQFEcQL2T7UrMyB8Lpf4x3MSqcklC-buxT50j9RYQR8b1r6xCnRgFEYYfJwY8XgzHbe2zh50om0dM7dIFAWVLqHaBF836MVVAQc3MzrE2TyvYddzMB44QFZ5GMhco5BLNSfB3784ostlMPexcJhyaGD4yKB2HoMa5oUXTcjMSw5_mtMC0pQCOujZ2kz8vODwsaqvv8Afl9xI3YTdCYPgph-Oi2-6h_nwy0hk68CvFUqwqbL_7Xv39R-NmVoQMdU2wsHYncjmUQCn9EoKbhyosDLFKVK_i3KjVUhrQDR-qeIfzJt5ZLopuHqMAOJSqOHg,,&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1Ldmtxa1dJcnh6My1HZmVWTDNETF9GMVhFWnBXblp6Ry00Rzk0MEYxOXF5YklzWXBDakdkbGQ4WUkyZi1uVTNPWEVaMEhlSXlyVEVKNGdmYTN4NTJ2VFBlZWtPai1CWlZ3NlZVdyws&sign=2c6a945add5bae7fc58bd0078dd2b52c&keyno=0&b64e=2&ref=orjY4mGPRjk5boDnW0uvlrrd71vZw9kpxMQTG7KCjmz_d8k9GEVJNJgypfxf0G9wqKn_oCj0d3w-M1rkqdA-_UVzIHX693BNa1UPwtKuZxi8JEDKmnfXAHI0SBMQTAl2bnXqzio37t8F0iTUzdBgI8cUwZVOHihxwUnC_l2sVV0Q2UtsJcQCfXaKuVGhNJiQQicuaUcz7RdAYZiI3XUZ1An4IS5erkM7YX9TZwYjHHU,&l10n=ru&cts=1513697237164&mc=2.2359263506290326) is the Russian edition, but the proof is essentially a formula.

Comment: Thank you, the proof is very clear from the two formulas in the proof! (The formula in the statement should be an equality between *determinants*, and so should be the last one, right?)

Comment: [English translation of the 1994 edition](http://staff.math.su.se/mleites/books/prasolov-1994-problems.pdf).

Comment: Yes, for determinants. Maybe, your theorem is rather 1.2.6.3 (1.2.6.1 is for angular minors).

Comment: (there was a typo, which in the English translation has been fixed)

Comment: strange: the Russian version is much more fresh

Comment: Actually, your Yandex link doesn't work for me, but here is Prasolov's Russian version in its 2nd edition: http://prasolov.loegria.net/linalg.pdf . And yeah, lots of the parentheses should be determinants. Anyone care to tell Prasolov? (While at that, also mention that the chain of inequalities in Theorem 1.2.11.1 is ambiguous, since the commas may either separate inequalities or separate variables.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg he welcomes all information about misprints

Comment: Mail has been sent.

Comment: Ouch -- I've been looking at the 1st edition (or the 1.5th edition?) all along. The 2nd edition can be found at https://sites.google.com/site/prasolovskacatmoiknigi/ .

Answer (score 4):

You might try using the very interesting combinatorial approach of Doron Zeilberger in *A Combinatorial Approach to Matrix Algebra*, Discrete Mathematics **56** (1985), 61-72. There he gives short proofs of various matrix results such as the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem and the Matrix-Tree Theorem as combinatorial identities, which for me is the "right" way to understand these, rather than appealing to, for example, properties of complex matrices and eigenvalues.

Comment: This may work, but probably not as easily as the proofs in Zeilberger's paper. The comment by André Camargo in https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2017/08/28/dodgson-condensation-from-schur-complementation/ (from 30 August, 2017 at 7:25 pm) sketches how the $r = n$ case can be obtained from Sylvester's identity (which is combinatorially proven in [a paper by Berliner and Brualdi](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.531.364)). I suspect the same argument goes through for all $r$, but have not checked.