# Gram determinant in dual basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $V$ is a $n$ -dimensional inner product space.
Basis $(e_1,...,e_n)$, $(f_1,...,f_n)$ are said to be dual if 
$\langle e_i, f_j\rangle=0$ for  $i\neq j$, $i,j=1,...,n$ and $\langle e_i, f_i\rangle=1$ for $i=1,...,n$.

The Gram determinant of vectors $x_1,...,x_r\in V$ is the determinant 
$G(x_1,...,x_r)=\det[\langle x_i,x_j\rangle]$.

For dual basis $(e_1,...,e_n)$, $(f_1,...,f_n)$ we have:
$f_i=\sum_{j=1}^n  g^{i j}e_j$ for $i=1,...,n$, where $g^{ij}$ are elements of the inverse matrix to  $[g_{ij}]$ with $g_{ij}=\langle e_i,e_j\rangle$.

Is it true for fixed $p\in \{1,...,n-1 \}$ the formula 
$$
\frac{G(e_1,..,e_p)}{G(f_{p+1},...,f_{n})}=G(e_1,...,e_n)
$$
and how to prove it.

Comment: This is a consequence of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87877/jacobis-equality-between-complementary-minors-of-inverse-matrices , since $G\left(f_1, \ldots, f_n\right) = G\left(e_1, \ldots, e_n\right)^{-1}$.